# Angular l10n localization - load translation in separate modules - does not trigger translationChanged

Tags: angular

I am trying to set up localization with angular l10n library. I successfully implemented a module and initialized it before the UI is loaded for main translation. Now my intention is to have separate translation files/endpoints for every module and lazy load it on top of the default initialization.

This is module I came up, let's call it SomeModule

```
import { Injectable, NgModule, Inject, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LocaleService, TranslationService, TranslationModule, LocalizationModule, L10nLoader, L10N_CONFIG, L10nConfig, L10nConfigRef, ProviderType } from 'angular-l10n';
import { SomeComponent } from './some.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SomeComponent
  ]
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LocalizationModule,
    TranslationModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    TranslationModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  entryComponents: [SomeComponent]
})

export class SomeModule {
  constructor(
    @Inject(L10N_CONFIG) 
    public l10nLoader: L10nLoader,
    private configuration: L10nConfigRef, 
    private translation: TranslationService,
  ) {
    this.load();
  }

  load() {
    this.configuration.translation.providers = [
      { type: ProviderType.Static, prefix: './api/main/' },
      { type: ProviderType.Static, prefix: './api/other/' }
    ];

    this.l10nLoader.load().then(() => {
      this.translation.init();
      // this.translation.loadTranslation();
    })
  }
}
```

By accessing the L10nConfigRef I managed to add there more providers on top of the default init translation. I could see in the browser network that the translation is successfully loaded.

The problem is, it's loaded after all my view/components and it does not refresh the translation.

So how could I reinitialized the translation and manually trigger/emit the translationChanged?

The this.translation.init() does not work neither this.translation.loadTranslation() - the latest is not even a public method in the library so that's neither the right way.

Any other suggestion how to reinit the library and trigger translationChanged?